# Get a column is participating in a primary key or not?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, database-schema

I'm selecting my table schema data like this

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()
ORDER BY table_name, ordinal_position
```

I'm getting all column related data in that. How can I get whether a column is participating in a primary key or not with Y or N like this

ColumnName Primary key

t1          Y
t2          N

Comment: Put `EXPLAIN` in the front of your query, then you will find out which indexes are being used and in which order

Comment: This is a duplicate although the other question is about SQL Server. The information_schema however is part of the SQL ANSI-Standard '92 and it works the same for MySQL.